# how to use CSS Attribute Selectors? ! input[type=checkbox]

Tags: css

i want use CSS Attribute Selectors.Similar to the code `! input[type=checkbox]`
all of input's, without select checkbox's. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selects every `input` that is not a `input[type="checkbox"]` element

```
input:not(input[type=checkbox])
```

You can find more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: The second `input` seems rather redundant; `input:not([type=checkbox])` would achieve the same.